# How can I find custom UTIs App support in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uti

I'm developing a custom UTI like "com.xyz".

All the apps supporting this UTI may be shown in the `UIActivityViewController`.

Code snippet:

```
let extensionItem = NSExtensionItem()

let data = NSItemProvider.init(item: nil, typeIdentifier: "com.xyz")
extensionItem.attachments = [data]

let activity = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [extensionItem],
    applicationActivities: nil
)
present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In order to have a better user experience, I would like to check if the iOS device has any App supporting "com.xyz" before presenting the `UIActivityViewController`.

Just like check URL:

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
```

Otherwise the user may see an empty `UIActivityViewController` without any app.

As I know, there is an `ActivityNotFoundException` could be try and catch to handle the app not found situation in Android.
Does iOS support something like `ActivityNotFoundException`?

THANKS!

[image: empty UIActivityViewController]

Comment: If the UTI is custom, how can _any_ other app support it? You are supposed to provide unique UTI string; the whole idea is that _no_ other app should ever have heard of it. Otherwise it's not custom.

Comment: Yes, The idea is that i provide the UTI "com.xyz" to the other. if the iOS device currently is no app supporting "com.xyz". I hope to present an alertController that recommends user to download any app supporting "com.xyz".

Comment: But how can there be one if you just invented it?

Comment: For instance, the UTI is "com.adobe.pdf" but the iOS device currently does have any app support "com.adobe.pdf". Could i know it before present the UIActivityViewController?

Comment: But com.adobe.pdf is not “custom”. It is just the opposite. It is a well known official UTI.

Comment: Ok, Then i revise the question into "Could i check UTI 'com.adobe.pdf' supported app in iOS device before presenting the UIActivityViewController ?"